# Two output files share the same path but have different contents node_modules\.vite\deps_temp\@apollo_Client.js

Tags: reactjs, vite

I'm new to React and trying vitejs for the first time.  I keep getting this error in the console when I start the server and I have no idea as to how to troubleshoot this error. Here is the error:

```
Use GraphQL at http://localhost:3001/graphql
[1] X [ERROR] Two output files share the same path but have different contents: node_modules\.vite\deps_temp\@apollo_Client.js    
[1]
[1] C:\Users\judo2\Documents\dev\my-sites\mat-house\client\node_modules\esbuild\lib\main.js:1624
[1]   let error = new Error(`${text}${summary}`);
[1]               ^
[1]
[1] Error: Build failed with 1 error:
[1] error: Two output files share the same path but have different contents: node_modules\.vite\deps_temp\@apollo_Client.js       
[1]     at failureErrorWithLog (C:\Users\judo2\Documents\dev\my-sites\mat-house\client\node_modules\esbuild\lib\main.js:1624:15)  
[1]     at C:\Users\judo2\Documents\dev\my-sites\mat-house\client\node_modules\esbuild\lib\main.js:1266:28
[1]     at runOnEndCallbacks (C:\Users\judo2\Documents\dev\my-sites\mat-house\client\node_modules\esbuild\lib\main.js:1046:63)    
[1]     at buildResponseToResult (C:\Users\judo2\Documents\dev\my-sites\mat-house\client\node_modules\esbuild\lib\main.js:1264:7) 
[1]     at C:\Users\judo2\Documents\dev\my-sites\mat-house\client\node_modules\esbuild\lib\main.js:1377:14
[1]     at C:\Users\judo2\Documents\dev\my-sites\mat-house\client\node_modules\esbuild\lib\main.js:678:9
[1]     at handleIncomingPacket (C:\Users\judo2\Documents\dev\my-sites\mat-house\client\node_modules\esbuild\lib\main.js:775:9)   
[1]     at Socket.readFromStdout (C:\Users\judo2\Documents\dev\my-sites\mat-house\client\node_modules\esbuild\lib\main.js:644:7)  
[1]     at Socket.emit (node:events:527:28)
[1]     at addChunk (node:internal/streams/readable:315:12) {    
[1]   errors: [
[1]     {
[1]       detail: undefined,
[1]       id: '',
[1]       location: null,
[1]       notes: [],
[1]       pluginName: '',
[1]       text: 'Two output files share the same path but have different contents: node_modules\\.vite\\deps_temp\\@apollo_Client.js'
[1]     }
[1]   ],
[1]   warnings: []
[1] }
```

Comment: It's just like they say: The two hardest things in computer science are cache invalidation and naming things.

Answer (score 8):

```
**import React from "react";** 

import React from "React"; -> error
```

The same error occurred to me and I solved it with the above I was using react

Answer (score 2):

I found out that in my App.jsx file I was trying to import from '@apollo/Client' rather than '@apollo/client'.  I found it by accident when I tried rebuilding it react and that one showed the file where the issue was happening where in vite it did not.